# Пагинация php и mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, пагинация

Как здесь сделать пагинацию? В идеале двумя способами: обычная пагинация ( < 1 2 3 4 5 > ) и в добавок через кнопку "Показать еще" (дозагружать строки на той же странице)

```
<table class="table table-inverse table-striped table-bordered table-hover" style="margin-top:20px;">
  <tbody>
          <?php 

             $link = mysqli_connect($host, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

             if (!$link) {
                 echo "Ошибка: Невозможно установить соединение с MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
                 echo "Код ошибки errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
                 echo "Текст ошибки error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
                 exit;
             }             

             mysqli_query($link, "set names utf8");          



             $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `panel` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0 , 1000000;");
             if ($link->affected_rows > 0)
             {
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
              {

                 if (!isset($row['birthday']) || empty($row['birthday']) || $row['birthday'] == '0000-00-00')
                 {
                  $row['birthday'] = '';    
                 } else {
                  $row['birthday'] = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($row['birthday']));
                 }

                 echo('
<tr>
 <td>
    <div class="dataRow" data-row="'.$row['id'].'">
      <div><strong>Имя:</strong> <span id="name">'.$row['name'].'</span> <strong>Фамилия:</strong> <span id="surname">'.$row['surname'].'</span> <strong>Дата рождения:</strong> <span id="birthday">'.$row['birthday'].'</span></div>
      <div><strong>Город:</strong> <span id="city">'.$row['city'].'</span> <strong>Телефон:</strong> <span id="phone">'.$row['phone'].'</span></div>
      <div><strong>Адрес:</strong> <span id="address">'.$row['address'].'</span></div>
      <div><strong>Вопрос:</strong> <span id="question">'.$row['question'].'</span></div>
      <div><strong>Ссылка на фото:</strong> <span id="photo" style="display:none;">'.$row['photo'].'</span><img src="'.$row['photo'].'" style="max-width:300px; max-height:500px;"></div>
      ');
      if ($_SESSION['user'] == 'admin')
      {

          echo('<div><strong>Дни:</strong> <span id="days">'.$row['days'].'</span> ');

          if (!isset($row['birthday']) || empty($row['birthday']) || $row['birthday'] == '')
          {
           $row['birthday'] = '';    
          } else {
           $row['birthday'] = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($row['birthday']));
           echo('<strong>Дата рождения + Количество дней: </strong> '.date("d.m.Y", strtotime("+".$row['days']." day", strtotime($row['birthday']))).'</div> ');              
          }          

      } else {

          if (!isset($row['birthday']) || empty($row['birthday']) || $row['birthday'] == '')
          {
           $row['birthday'] = '';    
          } else {
           $row['birthday'] = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($row['birthday']));
           echo('<div><strong>Дата рождения + Количество дней: </strong> '.date("d.m.Y", strtotime("+".$row['days']." day", strtotime($row['birthday']))).'</div> ');
          }   


      }
      echo('<div class="text-right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm edit" edit="'.$row['id'].'"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delButton" del="'.$row['id'].'"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> </div>
    </div>
 </td>
</tr>
    ');
              }
             } else {
                 echo('<tr><td class="text-center">Пусто</td></tr>');
             }
             mysqli_close($link);

          ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: С этим способом мучаюсь
http://phpfaq.ru/mysql/paginator
Не получается